# How could I install Tensorflow Object Detection on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm a bit stuck I'm following a tutorial for object detection and I couldn't install Tensorflow Object Detection on my virtual environnement I tried this code without success. There is probably a better solution but I didn't find a way to solve my problem.

```
!move protoc-3.15.8-osx-x86_64.zip {paths['PROTOC_PATH']}
!cd {paths['PROTOC_PATH']} && tar -xf protoc-3.15.8-osx-x86_64.zip
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(paths['PROTOC_PATH'], 'bin')) 
!apt-get install protobuf-compiler
!cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && python -m pip install .
```

I got /bin/bash: move: command not found
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'protoc-3.15.8-osx-x86_64.zip'
when I executed my code.

I tried to create this code from this one in windows:

```
url="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.15.6/protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip"
    wget.download(url)
    !move protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip {paths['PROTOC_PATH']}
    !cd {paths['PROTOC_PATH']} && tar -xf protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip
    os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(paths['PROTOC_PATH'], 'bin'))   
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && copy object_detection\\packages\\tf2\\setup.py setup.py && python setup.py build && python setup.py install
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research/slim && pip install -e .
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you just run "!tar" by itself? Also, "Command not found tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open" is probably a helpful query to search for.

Comment: Hi J369, I tried but unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: Can you include that error? As in just "!tar", without the -xf proto[...].

Comment: If I understood well without -xf proto[...]: I got must specify one of -c, -r, -t, -u, -x

Comment: @J369 I edited my question and add the equivalent code in windows, this one works but trying to get the same on my mac

Comment: Maybe try the "unzip" command instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to install it with another method found on Medium https://medium.com/@viviennediegoencarnacion/how-to-setup-tensorflow-object-detection-on-mac-a0b72fbf470a